# Any ideas on how to use Google Closure Compiler to combine multiple javascript files w/o any optimizations?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Any ideas on how to use Google Closure Compiler to combine multiple JavaScript files w/o any optimizations?  Specifically, we want to use Closure to deploy two versions of our combined site JavaScript: release and debug.  For release, we are using `--compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --manage_closure_dependencies` which is working as intended.  However, for debug, we would like our JavaScript to be combined intact/unmodified for easier debugging.  It seems the minimum level of optimization is `WHITESPACE_ONLY`, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's an option to format the processed JavaScript file using the `--formatting PRETTY_PRINT`. The option indents/formats (with whitespace) the output JavaScript file, such that the JavaScript is easily debuggable.

Wish the documentation is a little more detailed/complete :)

Answer (score 4):

```
--formatting PRETTY_PRINT for beautifying
--debug true for meaningful names (after Advanced compilation)
```

Comment: Does the '--debug true' flag only apply to Advance compilations (ie not simple)?

Comment: It is not only for Advanced mode.  In Advanced mode, property and function names are changed.  If you turn on debug, all the names got renamed into a version that contains the original name (only different), so you can immediately find out which property name is giving you the problem.  In simple mode, you don't need that because properties and functions are not renamed, but you can still use --debug to find out what local variables are renamed to.

Answer (score 4):

Concatenation works like you'd expect it:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js 1.js --js 2.js --js_output_file out.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts come to mind immediately.  First - Why use closure compiler for that task, why not just something like `cat jsfile1.js jsfile2.js > debug.js`?  Second - [Closure Inspector](http://code.google.com/p/closure-inspector/downloads/list) will allow you to debug code compiled with Closure Compiler using FireBug.

> To help you work with your transformed code, you can also install the [Closure Inspector](http://closure-inspector.googlecode.com/files/closureinspector09.xpi), a tool that makes it easy to use the Firebug JavaScript debugger with the Compiler's output.

Comment: We can't simply concatenate the JavaScript files in debug, because we still depend on closure to manage JavaScript dependencies.  I will look into using Closure Inspector, the only challenge would be if we need to debug an issue in another browser.