# Can I use Google Closure only for concatenating JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a project moved into my hands recently. It uses Google Closure to compile multiple JS files into one final.js. Sometimes I need to debug final.js in the browser, but the problem is Closure always compress JavaScript code with shorten function and variable names. So I can't debug final.js properly in the browser.

My question is, is there any way to use Google Closure to just concatenate JS files without compressing?

The answer can be some CLI options or even hacking the source code.

PS. I've tried `--formatting PRETTY_PRINT`, but the final code still got compressed.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198915/any-ideas-on-how-to-use-google-closure-compiler-to-combine-multiple-javascript-f/13230424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHITESPACE_ONLY and PRETTY_PRINT get pretty close, but there isn't a "concat" only mode.  The compiler does have the capability to create "output bundles" but it isn't exposed on the command-line:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/52ae79693589834930cbfc01fe78f4efa8f6c518/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/AbstractCommandLineRunner.java#L1966

Comment: The problem with WHITESPACE_ONLY is that it doesn't combine the files in the right order, paying attention to goog.require(). What we really need is a way to do the combining, leaving the files unminified. That makes it possible for debugging before we minify for production.

Comment: If whitespace only mode doesn't order things properly, please file a issue as it should be ordered if the dependency options are in use. You can file one here:
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/new

Comment: The project rejected our [issue](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/555), saying that whitespace_only is not supposed to order things or support goog.require().

Comment: You didn't respond to later comments.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off just writing a batch file or a bash script to do this. something like this should work for what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del output.js
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do ( 
    type !argVec[%%i]! >> output.js
    echo. >> output.js
)
```

usage

```
joinjs file1.js file2.js file3.js ...
```

Comment: This isn't going to do the same thing, particularly with regard to ordering files properly and goog.require().