# How to concatenate/combine but not compress with Closure Compressor?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I have multiple JavaScript files that are concatenated with Closure using "Scripts/**.js".  I would like to build site.js and site.min.js versions.

Is there a way to concatenate but not compress/minify?

Comment: Why the hell would someone down vote this? It's clear, concise and doesn't violate any rule of stack overflow. Have an upvote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any ideas on how to use Google Closure Compiler to combine multiple javascript files w/o any optimizations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198915/any-ideas-on-how-to-use-google-closure-compiler-to-combine-multiple-javascript-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `@compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY` but that still does more than just concatenate.

Really, if all you want is to concatenate, have a simple script which reads each file and outputs each line into a new file. Between each file write a `\n` to the new file.

Comment: I had tunnel vision, wasn't think outside of Closure.  Doing the concatenate sounds like a good idea.  I also just found the --debug property which might be good for the non minified version.

Answer (score 1):

The compile has the capability but is isn't exposed:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/580